# locust script goes back to initial step after an client post

Tags: locust

I have a locust script with multiple steps as below..

```
    @task(1)
    step 1 - Setup step 1
    step 2 - Setup step 2
    step 3 - Setup step 3
    step 4 - Do a post **self.client.get(...)**
    step 5 - Do some additional setup
    step 6 - Do a patch **self.client.patch(...)**
    step 7 - Do some additional setup
    step 8 - Do a get **self.client.get(...)**
```

When I run the above step using multiple users, steps 1 to 4 are run multiple times before continuing to the next steps. I would like each user to complete all the steps before restarting the task by another user. Please help

Comment: If you dont want concurrent Users, just launch only 1 user.

Comment: Hi Cyberwiz, thanks for your response. Are you saying that once a user hit step 4 - self.client.___, a new user ramp up? I was thinking the same so I have tried with different wait_time like 2, 4, 6, 8 `wait_time = between(2, 4)`, but in all cases, I see the script goes back to step 1 right after step 4. That is what confusing me

Comment: Well kind of. Once a User reaches the end of a task it will (after waiting) run it again. It is not a ”new” user though.

Comment: I was hoping a user would go all the way to the last step, in my case to step 8, before restarting or going back to step 1. However, it seems like it is going back to the first step right after step 4 which has a HTTPS call.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see the number of steps. Yea, that is how it is supposed to work. Maybe step 5 is throwing an exception? No way to know what is going wrong without your actual code.

Comment: @Cyberwiz The script is running without any issue. For some reason it just restarts as soon as it hits `self.client..` Thank you so much for your help so far.